# Earth View as default for Google Maps

Tags: firefox, google-maps, google-earth

I frequently use Earth View (the one like in external Google Earth program) on `maps.google.com` as I find it more pleasant and quick rather then the laggy map and satellite views. However, every time one visits `maps.google.com` one has manually to switch to Earth View.

Is it possible to make the EV default when visiting `maps.google.com`?

Comment: Are you logged in to your Google/Gmail account?

Comment: Aye, i am. And i tried setting a default _location_, which works. However, the default view is still the painted map.

Comment: Hmm. I just installed the Google Earth plugin to test this out. I am experiencing the same thing as you.

Comment: Google Maps remembers if were using the `Satellite` or `Map` view, but not the `Earth` view.

Comment: You can choose the default view if you are using the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) on your own webpage, but I have not found a way to do this on the Google Maps website.

Comment: Yes, i see. Thank you for your input, and i’m glad that you could confirm this. Let us keep looking! :)